# Next-best option in lieu of 'oneOf' in swagger (v2.0)

Tags: json, rest, validation, swagger

I've recently been diving back into REST and am looking for a tool with decent support for [JSON-Schema](http://json-schema.org/).

I'm using Swagger, and I began this project fully aware the Swagger implementation of JSON-Schema was incomplete.  What's the cleanest workaround for Swagger's lack of support for the `oneOf` constraint?  (In my project, the `oneOf` requirement can't simply be dropped.)

**EDIT**:
Running through the JSON-Schema spec again last night I had the thought of trying to force 'enum' for this purpose.  Objects in an enum element are **literal** and must be known ahead of time and used verbatim.  In other words, the objects defined in an enum cannot be used as schema definitions or a substitute for 'oneOf'.

**EDIT 2**
oneOf is now supported in OpenAPI 3.0
https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3#properties

Comment: in what context do you exactly need oneOf ? Is it for specifying entries for a parameter - oneOf a list would be permitted..or parameters themselves (oneOf the two parameters must be entered)?

Comment: Sampada, The main object I am modeling has an array of objects where each of the objects are from a list of compatible objects.  A very crude example might be [ String, Number, String, String ] where validation for each of the objects could be handled by their own definition.  Each object in the array can only be "one of" the compatible objects.

Comment: `oneOf` is now supported in OpenAPI 3.0.